# Iterate table and check differences values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I create this example:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eqzKZp)

```js
$('.diff').on('click', function() {
  // create a function that check values between elements
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button class="diff">See Difference</button>

    <button class="diff">See Difference</button>

<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="row-attribute>
         <th class="col-1">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               SKU         
            </div>
         </th>
         <td class="col-2">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               mazda-rx-8-duo-reges:                  
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="col-3">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               zenvo-st1-quod-dicit       
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-attribute>
         <th class="col-1">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               Model         
            </div>
         </th>
         <td class="col-2">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               RX-8        
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="col-3">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               ST1           
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-attribute">
         <th class="col-1">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               Number of doors              
            </div>
         </th>
         <td class="col-2">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               4                 
            </div>
         </td>
         <td class="col-3">
            <div class="cell-inner">
               4                                          
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to go interate into this table and check if there is a difference between the values ​​and if there is a highlight with a background color.

I want add or remove a CSS class on that row where there is a difference between the elements.

Can you please change my example so that what I wanted to happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you building that table? Can you change the table/process which builds it include ids - that'd make things much cleaner and faster, all you need is to come up with a naming convention.

Comment: I clean my html code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for a solution without trying to solve the problem themself first. Referring to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.)

Comment: You could use jQuery selectors for finding all rows (`.find`), iteration (`.each`) and selection of column values to find the differences.